# Databound Content Controls not Updating in Word Online

Tags: xml, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I have some content controls data-bound to custom XML parts in my document. I use my Office JS add-in in Word to update the custom XML parts.

In Word 2016 for Windows, the content controls refresh and contain the updated values from the custom XML parts.

However, in Word Online, even though the custom XML parts are updated, the content controls remain unchanged.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT: The new viewer now displays the document correctly.** Leaving the below for posterity / future me.

I think it's telling that the new viewer fails to show content controls correctly:

[image]

---

There has still not been any official word yet on this, though. Relevant links:

[Office Developer Platform UserVoice suggestion](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/13542930-content-control-support-in-word-online)

[Microsoft Answers forum post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeonline-word_online/content-control-support-in-word-online/0f33ba70-9fe0-4990-9f09-db5ce7f3a8c7)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this feature is not supported in Word Online.

Comment: Yes; but see [UserVoice suggestion](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/13542930-content-control-support-in-word-online). This feature [has been requested since at least early 2013](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeonline-word_online/does-word-web-app-support-editing-documents-with/327745a0-64a2-475a-9b40-3e85cd17f244) and [promised to be delivered here by Juan Balmori](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeonline-word_online/content-control-support-in-word-online/0f33ba70-9fe0-4990-9f09-db5ce7f3a8c7).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say it clearly. The ContentControl editing feature is enabled, but ContentControl binds to a custom xml is not supported yet.

Comment: Can you share a rough timeline of when the feature as required in my question will be available for Word Online? In short: any update to a custom XML part should automatically update all content controls bound to it in Word Online, as is possible in Word 2016 for Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Rich text content controls are supported now in Word Online, and all the Javascript APIs work on them. 
However there are a few functionalities that are still not supported, binding to XML parts is one of them. This will be added in the future ETA is unknown at this point.

Comment: Can you share a rough timeline of when the feature as required in my question will be available for Word Online? In short: any update to a custom XML part should automatically update all content controls bound to it in Word Online, as is possible in Word 2016 for Windows and Mac.

Comment: That's correct and the team is very aware of this, however i cannot disclose a timeline at this point. sorry about this.

Comment: It is now mid-July 2018, can you share a timeline of this now, or even an idea of where the team is at regarding this feature?